# How do I make a counter with jQuery that also keeps high score?

Tags: jquery, animation, math

I'm working on making a really simple counter for trivia games that also keeps the high score. It's working decently well except for two problems:

1) When I click refresh current score to get the current score back to zero, it refreshes properly but then as soon as I start clicking the score button it resets the high score as well.

2) My .animate() won't work on either and I don't understand why?

Here's my HTML:

```
<header class="controls">
    <div id="refresh-score"></div>
    <p class="scoreboard">HIGH | <span id="high-score-value"></span></p>
</header>
<h1 class="title-big" id="current-score-value"><div id="overlay"></div></h1>
<div id="score-button">+</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="car-trivia.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    var currentScore = 0;
    var highScore = 0;

    $('#high-score-value').append(highScore);

    $('#current-score-value').append(currentScore);

    $('#refresh-score').click(function(){
        console.log("refresh click");
        currentScore = 0;
        $('#current-score-value').html(currentScore);
        $('#refresh-score').animate({
            transform: "rotate(-360deg)"
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#score-button').click(function(){
        console.log("score click");
        currentScore++;
        $('#current-score-value').html(currentScore);
        if (currentScore > highScore) {
            $('#high-score-value').html(currentScore);
        } else {
            $('#high-score-value').html(highScore);
        }
    };

    $('.overlay').animate({
        width: "200vw",
        height: "200vw"
        }, 500)
    });

})
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cut out the animation stuff, because that is working if you don't make mistakes with braces and bracket. You never updated your `var highScore` so your logic did not add up anymore after hitting the refresh button, see the comment in the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/xukh3p3e/2/

```
$(function(){
        var currentScore = 0;
        var highScore = 0;

        $('#high-score-value').append(highScore);

        $('#current-score-value').append(currentScore);

        $('#ref').click(function(){
            console.log("refresh click");
            currentScore = 0;
            $('#current-score-value').html(currentScore);
            $('#ref').animate({
                transform: "rotate(-360deg)"
            }, 500);
        });

        $('#score-button').click(function(){
            console.log(highScore);
            console.log(currentScore);
            currentScore++;

            $('#current-score-value').html(currentScore);
            if (currentScore > highScore) {
                $('#high-score-value').html(currentScore);
                 highScore++;//MUST UPDATE HIGHSCORE VARIABLE HERE :)
            } else {
                $('#high-score-value').html(highScore);
            }
        });

        $('.overlay').animate({
            width: "200vw",
            height: "200vw"
            }, 500);
        });
```

Comment: So all you did was add the e.preventDefault()?
Because that shouldn't be an issue since the refresh button is actually just a div, not a button. 

Also, I don't have any errors in my console. What errors did you notice?

Would seeing my HTML/CSS help?

Comment: Sorry, I added an empty fiddle but it should be fine now. I am not sure if I had console errors but there were som mistakes with brackets and braces.

Comment: Yep I have taken a look at it and I see that your logic does not add up. I have created you a working fiddle and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mikey! I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep yet. Thanks much tho!

Comment: @realjoet No problem, btw I know you can't vote up but you can accept the answer even with low rep and it will earn you some reputation yourself ;)